# System.NullReferenceException Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

**I want to delete the selected stack panel but when I select the stackpanel it give exception**

```
            <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" Background="{x:Null}"        
                     Margin="-2,51,-4,647" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Tag="{Binding Weight_ID}"  
                                   Tapped="StackPanel_Tapped"  >

                         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="date" Text=" Date">                      
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date_}" >
                         </StackPanel>    
                         </StackPanel>
                         </DataTemplate>
                         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                         </ListBox>


    private void StackPanel_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

       string id = (((e.OriginalSource) as TextBlock).Tag).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: And your question is? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: try to replace from ListBox to ListVIew and use ItemClick event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Tapped event handler on the Stackpanel, use ItemClick event handler on a listView and type cast the content you want